# IQueryable changed in foreach loop not displaying in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, gridview, foreach, iqueryable

I been trying to change the value of `RouteAttr.RoutedForRole` if it is equal to 
 `SHead` but I checked in run time and the `query` was not changed even though it went to the foreach loop and there were valid entries. I also tried adding the foreach loop in the view but it didn't change anything.

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    IQueryable<ServiceRequestViewModel> query;
    query = from c in context.ServiceRequests
            select new ServiceRequestViewModel
            {
                ServiceRequestId = c.ServiceRequestId,
                ServiceDescription = c.ServiceDescription,
                RequestNumber = c.RequestNumber,
                Title = c.Title,
                RouteAttr = c.RouteAttr,
                LogAttr = c.LogAttr
            };

    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        if (item.RouteAttr.RoutedForRole == WorkflowRole.SHead)
        {
            item.RouteAttr.RoutedForRole = WorkflowRole.HRManager;
        }
    }
    return View(query);
}
```

Below is my gridview.

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(col =>
{
    col.Add(o => o.ServiceRequestId)
        .Encoded(false)
        .Sanitized(false)
        .Filterable(true)
        .Titled("SRF No.")
        .SetWidth(150)
        .RenderValueAs(o => Html.ActionLink(o.RequestNumber, "Details", new { id = o.ServiceRequestId }));
    col.Add(o => o.Title)
        .Filterable(true)
        .SetWidth(400)
        .Titled("Title");
    col.Add(o => o.LogAttr.CreatedBy)
        .Filterable(true)
        .Titled("Requestor");
    col.Add(o => o.RouteAttr.RoutedForRole)
            .Filterable(true)
            .Titled("Status");
}).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true)
```

I've been told in the comments why it's not returning so now I want to know how to update an item in `iqueryable` and return it in view.

Comment: You're querying a database, I presume, and are bringing the results into memory, performing an update in-memory, but not saving it back to the database. When you return the query the query is re-executed against the database. You're just throwing away the changes you're making in the loop.

Comment: I don't want to change the data in db. I only want the display to change in view.

Comment: Then do a `var data = query.ToArray();`, change the data in `data` and then `return View(data);`

Comment: @Enigmativity `ServiceRequestViewModel` requires `System.Linq.IQueryable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like what @Enigmativity said in the comments, I changed the query into an array.

```
var data = query.ToArray();
```

He suggested I return `data` but it didn't work since `ServiceRequestViewModel` requires an `IQueryable` type. So I changed it back to `IQueryable` type so I can return it to view.

```
var queryable = data.AsQueryable();
```